# Hibernate save returns wrong generated id

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I am having trouble using Hibernate with MSSQL Server 2012. No matter what I do when I try to insert a value in a certain table using Hibernate I get generated id=0.

Here is the model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_ClientInfo")
public class ClientInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "auto_Client_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int auto_Client_ID;
    ...
```

Here is the write.

```
public boolean addNewClient(Client client) {
// there is a class that wraps SessionFactory as singleton
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer clientFamId; //client family info id
    Integer clientId;   // actual client id
    try {
        // create fam info first with some data - need id for ClientInfo
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        ClientFam clientFam = new ClientFam();
        clientFamId = (Integer) session.save(clientFam);
        clientFamId = (Integer) session.getIdentifier(clientFam); // this returns the right id 
        session.flush();

        ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
        clientInfo.setABunchOfFields(withStuff); //multiple methods
        session.save(clientInfo);
        clientInfoId = (Integer) session.getIdentifier(clientInfo); // this is always 0
        session.flush();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return true;
}
```

In the database the PK `auto_Client_ID` is clustered, set to `IDENTITY(1,1)`. Both `ClientInfo` and `ClientFam` records are created in the db, but hibernate returns 0. I also tried catching the value from `save`, but it's also 0.

I don't want to commit in-between separate insert: the transaction is when all inserts are fine (there are more after this, but I can't get to them because of this id issue yet).

The model for ClientFam is almost the same: the id field is `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` as well.

I also tried specifying this for `ClientInfo`

```
@GeneratedValue(generator="increment", strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
```

The first time I ran it it returned the correct value. However, the second time I ran it I got an error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Report' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

And that was the end of trying that. Everywhere I looked the recommendation is to use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` for auto incremented field in the db. That's supposed to return the right values. What might I be doing wrong?

I also tried getting the id from the `ClientInfo` object itself (I thought it should get written into it) after the right, but it's was also 0. Makes me think something is wrong with my `ClientInfo` model and/or annotations in it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with my situation - has nothing to do with Hibernate. There is a `instead of insert` trigger that wasn't returning id and hence messing up what `save()` returns.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess, but you might want to remove the "unique=true" clause from the @Column definition.  Hibernate may be handling the column as a unique constraint as opposed to a primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thierry. I tried that before with the same result. I had it like this earlier `@Column (name = "auto_Client_ID")`.